# reading commands with two words

Tags: java, command-line, input, java.util.scanner

So i'm doing a program on eclipse in java, and i have to read the commands(input) from the user,

```
e.g.: ADD <email> <phone>
```

this is done and it works, my problem is when the input has more than one word like :

```
e.g.: LIST USERS <email> <phone>
```

i have a while cycle, while(!comm.equals(Commands.EXIT.getMsg())) and then a bunch of ifs and elses(i cant use a switch) and i have this method

```
private static String getCommand(Scanner in) {
    String input = "";
    input = in.next().toUpperCase();
    return input;
    }
```

So has u can see my program only reads the first word and passes it as a command.
All the commands are constants and there are only 3commands with separate words.

---

What can i do to read the second word and pass it has a part of the command?
Where do i do it?In the while cycle or on my method getCommand?

Thank you in advance =)

Comment: You can test to see if the Scanner can read another String, then test whether or not the next String is a command.

Comment: I think you should use `readLine()` to get the entire input string and then `split` it into as many words as it has.

Comment: ^^ Agreed.  This problem seems like it would be best solved by capturing the complete input before you begin to process it.

Comment: else if(comm.equals(Commands.LIST.getMsg()) && in.hasNext()){
 comm = in.next();
        if(comm.equals(Commands.FILES.getMsg())){
     listFiles(in,c);
 }else if (comm.equals(Commands.USERS.getMsg())){
     listAllUsers(c);
 }  
}
@jahroy
I would like to try the first idea.i tried this but i dont think its right or even this way xD

Comment: Please do not add code in comments... It's unreadable.  You can simply edit your question.

Comment: Because of the way a Scanner works (it consumes input), you will be much better off to get the entire input from the user before processing it.  You should use the Scanner to get all of the strings.  Then you can pass the array/list of strings to a _getCommand()_ method.  If you in stead pass the Scanner to your _getCommand()_ method, it will consume the second String when you test it, and you won't be able to treat it as an argument (when it's not a command).  I know you want to continue to use your current code, but you should rewrite _getCommand()_ method to accept an array/list of strings.

Comment: thank you and sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use while loop:

```
List<String> input = new LinkedList<String>();
while(in.hasNext()){
   String param = in.next().toUpperCase();
   input.add(param);
}
```

For additional information, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)